# How to add a css class to an href in Silverstripe CMS editor?

Tags: silverstripe

How do you add a Class to an `href` or any other css element in the silverstripe CMS editor?

I have added a custom css Class in the `editor.css` stylesheet.

I want the link to look like this one:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="my-custom-class">Click me</a>
```

The way that I have tried to do it ends up with this result (e.g it wraps a `<p>` tag around the link):

```
<p class="my-custom-class">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Click me</a>
</p>
```

I realise you can use the HTML source code editor within the CMS editor to manually add in the class but want to try and avoid doing that if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen at [jonom's great TinyTidy module](https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-tinytidy/blob/master/_config.php#L108) you might try in your */mysite/_config.php*:

```
$formats = array(
    // Links

    array(
        'title' => 'Links'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Arrow',
        'attributes' => array('class'=>'arrow'),
        'selector' => 'a'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Button',
        'attributes' => array('class'=>'button'),
        'selector' => 'a'
    ),
);
//Set the dropdown menu options
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOption('style_formats',$formats);
```

Comment: Thank you! Works beautifully :)